# background color hide border-radius ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css3pie

I'm trying to do border-radius with ie8
here is my code:

```
position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#CCC', endColorstr='#C!C!C!', GradientType=0 );
    behavior: url(css/PIE.htc);
```

border-radius is here, but unfortunatelly it's under background color
what I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-pie-background`, not the old IE `filter` gradient.

From the PIE website

```
background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);
```